# Latex template for Scientific Reports (Nature)

Tags: templates

I've googled around a lot with, but I got no success. I hope I can find here some help.

Is there someone that can share a link to download a Latex template for the online journal Scientific Reports?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The journal recommend using either the article, revtex or amsart document classes. 
They say the following:

> TeX/LaTeX - Authors submitting LaTeX files may use any of the standard
>   class files such as article.cls, revtex.cls or amsart.cls.
>   Non-standard fonts should be avoided; please use the default Computer
>   Modern fonts. For the inclusion of graphics, we recommend
>   graphicx.sty. Please use numerical references only for citations.
>   References should be included within the manuscript file itself as our
>   system cannot accept BibTeX bibliography files. Authors who wish to
>   use BibTeX to prepare their references should therefore copy the
>   reference list from the .bbl file that BibTeX generates and paste it
>   into the main manuscript .tex file (and delete the associated
>   \bibliography and \bibliographystyle commands). As a final precaution,
>   authors should ensure that the complete .tex file compiles
>   successfully on their own system with no errors or warnings, before
>   submission.

All details for submitting an article to Scientific Reports can be found [here](http://www.nature.com/srep/authors/submit.html).