# How to download an Overleaf template?

Tags: templates, overleaf

[Scientific Reports](http://www.nature.com/srep/authors/submissions.html) now links to a [template on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns#.VNzKqC7HTlM).

I don't feel too well about uploading the sourcecode of my paper to some website I hadn't heard about before. That's why I tried to simply use the source of the template. The problem is I could not compile it myself since I do not have the classfile wlscirep.cls. Where can I get it?

Additionally, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150579/72735) to [Latex template for Scientific Reports (Nature)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150576/21344) seems to be still valid. Should I ignore the Overleaf template and simply use revtex like before?

Comment: OverLeaf is the old writeLatex, in case its old name gives you some confidence. You can alternatively open the template in overleaf, clone it using `git` with the link they give you, and that should download you the required class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very easy, you open the document ("Open as template"), and click on ["Project"](https://www.overleaf.com/2279315xgsgmq#/5849656/).
Then you can either "Download as zip" or just open the file "wlscirep.cls" directly online to view in the Overleaf editor.

I would use the template from Overleaf (either downloaded or online), that way you should always get the current requirements.

Comment: since overleaf documents have git access, is it possible to git-clone a template to always get the current requirements?

Answer (score 4):

"Download as zip" was not there in my case (2018/10/27) at project view.
However, by going up a view:

[image]

You can still download your project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

project -> choose a template -> open as template -> menu -> download as source

[image: ps]