# How to solve \headrow error?

Tags: threeparttable

`\headrow` is not working and give error on Overleaf:

```
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
```

even I use `\usepackage{threeparttable}`

How to solve that?

```
\begin{table}[bt]
\centering
\caption{Toy Students Dataset}
  \label{owakey}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\headrow
t & FirstName & LastName & HasFriend \\
student\_1&&&\\
    student\_2&&&---\\
    student\_3& &&\\ 
\hiderowcolors

\hline  % Please only put a hline at the end of the table
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

with `\documentclass[12pt]{memoireuqam1.3ang}`

Comment: `\headrow` is not a command of `threeparttable`, could you please add a minimal example which reproduces your error?

Comment: @CarLaTeX check please the example

Comment: I can't find any package which defines `\headrow`, why don't you simply use `\hline`? Or `\toprule` from `booktabs` package?

Comment: i need a table where a get an alternative row color

Comment: See if this post could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-to-create-alternating-rows-in-a-table

Comment: Could you please add where you got `memoireuqam1.3ang.cls` from?

Comment: you presumably saw some documentation that suggested a command called `\headrow` that document must have told you how to define it (it is not a standard command)

Comment: @leandriis There is the template on Overleaf. However, the command is not defined in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\headrow` is defined in a custom class developed by Overleaf called `wiley-article.cls` (see [Copy/paste code from Overleaf to LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408714/copy-paste-code-from-overleaf-to-latex)). The definition there is `\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}`, which fits your description of an 'alternative row color'. The `\rowcolor` command itself is provided by the `colortbl` package, which can be loaded using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. Loading `xcolor` also allows to use color specifications like `black!20` (20% black).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[bt]
\centering
\caption{Toy Students Dataset}
  \label{owakey}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\headrow
t & FirstName & LastName & HasFriend \\
student\_1&&&\\
    student\_2&&&---\\
    student\_3& &&\\ 
\hiderowcolors

\hline  % Please only put a hline at the end of the table
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]