# "Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'cite'." appears, though I don't use 'cite' package

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, bibliographystyle, cite-package, wlscirep

I am writing a thesis on Overleaf, but I have been struggling with this error.
This error occurs in the first 5 lines.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

I don't get why this incompatibility problem occurs though I am not using 'cite package' like (\usepackage{cite}).

Comment: Does the `wlscirep` document class load the `cite` package? (You should be able to tell by examining the log file.) I'm not familiar with that document class and it's not on CTAN so I can't test. (It infuriates me that Overleaf normalizes new document classes without putting them on CTAN.)

Comment: If it's the same as this version of [wlscirep.cls](https://github.com/SFICSSS16-CircularEconomy/Documents/blob/master/wlscirep.cls) here, then yes, it's what's loading `cite`. Either switch to a different document class or use bibtex instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. These help me a lot.
Just in case, is there a way to unload "cite" package while using the wlscirep document class? It seems that wlscirep is recommended to use for submitting this paper.

Comment: You could copy wlscirep.cls into your document's folder, and edit it by removing the line that loads `cite`, but using a modified version of the class almost certainly defeats the purpose. Is there a reason you can't use Bibtex?

Answer (score 3):

`wlscirep.cls` is not a class that is available on CTAN, but it can be obtained from Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns) if one has an Overleaf account, see also [How to download an Overleaf template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229205/35864).

The `wlscirep.cls` that can be obtained from that link identifies itself as

```
\ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[08/08/2020, v1.4]
```

The class loads

```
\RequirePackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
%% Nov 3, 2016: Support DOI
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
```

That is to say, the class hard-codes the `cite` package. The class is therefore incompatible with `biblatex`.

If you have to use the class for submission to your publisher, I would assume that the class already does the right thing for the bibliography and would not try to load `biblatex` instead.

Get rid of `biblatex` in your document and use the classical BibTeX approach. That is to say, cite using `\cite` and place `\bibliography{<your file name without .bib extension>}` in the document body where you want the bibliography list to appear.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's all clear. I will use bibtex instead.